# Centos 7 IPTABLES - SSH Lockout

Tags: iptables, centos7, firewalld

I'm currently ruunning an OVH dedicated box, which specifically, has the following operation system installed:

```
CentOS 7.1-1503
```

By default on CentOS 7 and above, the firewalld service is used instead of iptables. Sadly, I ran the following command:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

This was from a tutorial, and I wasn't scared because I knew iptables are meant to be flushed if not saved on restart, so I couldn't cause any permanent damage. However, it somehow automatically saved after several reboots.

I've tried:

- Entering rescue mode and adding a cronjob every minute to stop iptables and firewalld (didn't seem to do anything)
- Looking for the /usr/lib/firewalld directory which everyone talks about (definitely didn't exist)

I'm not sure where to go from here, but surely there's a solution?

To note, OVH's IPMI access didn't work as I never configured it so I don't think I can use the console. I've simply got FTP and a problem.

Error when I try console access:

```
Cannot open /home/shellinabox/input, ignoring
```

Comment: The IPMI certainly works and it does not need prior setup. Use it.

Comment: use rescue or single mode and edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, reboot and you're good to go)

Comment: IPMI really doesn't work, I wouldn't lie, and that directory doesn't exist sadly.